# nicedit enter makes paragraph (p) and not linebreak (br)

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I'm using Nicedit and face a problem with the "enter" button. Nicedit uses the paragraph tag and so there is a big whitespace between the lines, and i don't like that! Is there a way to make it use br, so there is not a big whitespace between the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to style the paragraph. http://www.sitepoint.com/fancy-paragraphs-css/

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> is what adds `<br>` like in every editor out there.

Comment: YEP i see now, but is there a way to force this? So if the user uses only enter that it behaves like shift enter?

Comment: I do not know the editor well enough to know if there is a setting, look in the docs.